# Metodo de una ruta resource no recibe argumento en laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, router

Estoy eliminando y editando en un crud sencillo con laravel 5.7 pero al usar una ruta resource con sus respectivos metodos de editar y eliminar (edit y destroy respectivamente), el metodo en cuestion no recibe el argumento id que le estoy pasando: Los codigos son estos:

Vista:

```
<form action="{{route('events.destroy',$event->id)}}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            @method('DELETE')
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>
</form>
```

Ruta:

```
Route::resource('events', 'EventController');
```

Controlador:

```
    public function destroy($id)
{ 
    dd($id);
}
```

La variable $event recibe el id, estoy recorriendo cada registro con un foreach... ya probe y si esta enviando la variable pero el metodo no la recibe el error es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No estoy completamente seguro en este momento, pero creo que te faltan `[]` al parametro que pasas, quedaria algo asi `{{route('events.destroy',[$event->id])}}`, cuando tenga acceso a mi pc y pueda confirmar esto te aviso, pero de memoria creo que era asi

Comment: Prueba y me avisas porque igual no pude, entre corchetes es cuando vas a pasar un array con clave => valor tengo entendido, pero cualquier cosa me avisas.

Answer (score 0):

Hermano ya revise, la forma en que yo paso los parámetros como tu los necesitas seria así:

```
{{ route('evaluations.analyst.check', ['evaluation_id' => $data->id]) }}
```

En tu caso debería ser algo así:

```
{{ route('events.destroy',['event_id' => $event->id]) }}
```

Así debería solucionarse tu error.